# c# Access DateTime UPDATE via DateTime.Parse

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-access, sql-update

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring)
con.Open()
cmdstring = "UPDATE table SET date="+DateTime.Parse(txtdate.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " WHERE id = 1"
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring,con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

When I try to update a table using this code in one of my forms it is done perfectly. But at the another form I'm using same code to update same table and same column, but I'm getting a confusing error. 
Syntax error(missing operator)

Example: Date at txtbox: 17.1.1987

Date at the error: 17.1.198

DateTime.Parse is okay. I tried what it is returning. It returns 4 digit year. But what is happening while updating access db?

Regards...

Comment: use this => "UPDATE table SET date = CONVERT(datetime, '" + txtdate.Text + "', 104) WHERE id = 1"

Comment: You probably need a space before WHERE in your example. In the actual code, since you are concatanating SQL string, you need to check the final SQL statement for any syntax errors before it executed.

Comment: Both inputs would work, as you've shown us. You'll need a bit more information. It would be useful to see the entire `cmdstring` for the failing case. That being said, you should probably parameterize your queries. It's not just safer, it's also neater and easier to reason about.

Comment: I had space i just before before WHERE. Sorr, I didn't put it here.
Updated code at the question.

Comment: "UPDATE table SET date = CONVERT(datetime, '" + txtdate.Text + "', 104) WHERE id = 1"
I'm using access db.Getting error: CONVERT function is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmdstring = "UPDATE table SET date='"+DateTime.Parse(txtdate.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' WHERE id = 1"
```

You need single quotes before and after value of date.

Comment: It is very strange. First I thought I tried with quotes. But it worked now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Always use parametrized queries. Especially when you deal with dates in Access you can run into so much trouble.

```
    DateTime dt;
    bool canParse = DateTime.TryParseExact(txtdate.Text,
                                      "dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                      DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                      out dt);
    if(canParse)
    {
         string sQuery = "UPDATE table SET date = @pdate WHERE ID = @pid";
         OleDbCommand updateCmd = new OleDbCommand(sQuery, Conn);
         updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@pdate", OleDbType.Date).Value = dt;
         updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@pid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1; 
         int rowsAffected = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         /* Use the result from operation for some notification */
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this at first opportunuty.